# ZK Framework and Geb for testing

Tags: java, zk, geb

I've got a web application in ZK Framework and I'd like to create implement some smoke tests using Geb.

Is it possible to test a ZK Framework app using Geb? I mean there's a lot of zul pages dynamically created so I guess it might be impossible.

Maybe you have some experience you can share in that matter.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the ID generator issue can be workarounded: [Implement ID Generator in ZK](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/Testing/Testing_Tips#Approach_2:_Implement_ID_Generator)

I have to take a deeper look at this...

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Geb depended on Selenium, so I think it should be possible to test with ZK.